# How can I split integer inside an array?

Tags: c++

In C++, I have the following input: `12345`

How can I achieve this output: `1 2 3 4 5` ?

---

**Another** example could be:

```
input: 123

output: 1 2 3
```

Comment: Read as a `std::string` and substract `'0'` from each position to get the digit numbers.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < YourString.Size(); i++) ACharVector.push_back(YourString[i]);`

Comment: @FirstStep Depends a bit on `AVector`'s type, if it's a `std::vector<int>` the substraction should be done as mentioned in my comment.

Comment: @PriteshJadhav As you may have noticed, your question isn't well achieved here, and it doesn't fit the intended format of good questions and answers that we want here. To learn basic stuff, it's probably better you read a book, or take on a tutorial.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ right. Then AnIntVector.push_back(YourStrin[i] - '0') should work or maybe (int)YourString[i] as well

Comment: @PriteshJadhav As it looks right now, any book would do well.

Comment: @Pritesh - You might want to search the site for "C++ Book", or go directly to [The Definitive C++ Book Guide And List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @PriteshJadhav You should notice, this isn't the way [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this:

```
int num = 123;
std::vector<int> digits;

while( num > 0 ) {
    digits.push_back(num % 10);
    num /= 10;
}
```

Comment: @PriteshJadhav Using something like `push_back(digit)` instead of `cout << digit` is an enormous intellectual act, I absolutely agree.

Comment: _@DimChtz_ I actually hesitate to up- or downvote your answer. On the one hand I don't think it's a good custom to answer off-topic questions. On the other hand I want to hinder the OP deleting that question themselves, but letting it go fully processed.